# How to replace double quotes if found only only as 1st and last character in a multiline string?

Tags: regex, csv

Not exactly a regex genius here, but so far I have this:  `(?>^)"|^(?!"$)` and this `(?>^)"(?<$)"`

But it is only capturing the first double quote here in the first regex, the latter is throwing error.

Here's a brief example multiline string:

```
8433|NTC Nano Tech Coatings GmbH|Marpinger Weg 2|||Tholey||D-66636|DE|1|EUR|        
"8434|Piramal Enterprises Ltd,|Plot No: 18, ""PHARMEZ"",|Pharma Special Economic|Zone,Sarkhej-Bawla NH #8AVilla|Ahmedabad||382213|IN|20|USD|"       
"8435|PolyDrop, LLC|22431 76th AVE S|||Kent|WA|98032|US|7|USD|"
```

I need a way to parse this via regex to remove the first " and last " on each line, but don't touch any other double quotes inside the lines.  Only replace them with an empty string if they are the 1st and last character of a line.

Can anyone help me here?  Seems I'm doing something wrong trying to get the last double quote for the last character of a line.

Comment: To match first and last double quotes on the lines use `(?m)^"|"$`

Comment: What flavor of regex parser?

Comment: PCRE I suppose with PHP. @WiktorStribiżew Looks like I need to account for the extra spaces at the end of the lines also.

Comment: Like `(?m)^\h*\K"|"(?=\h*$)`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - I believe that works.  Why is it so damn difficult to understand regex?  I really need to learn this language better.

Comment: please provide more input data. with at least 3 different output lines. You mentioned multiline, what is the multiline separator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match first and last double quotes on the lines accounting for any whitespace before the first and after the last quote, you may use

```
(?m)^\h*\K"|"(?=\h*$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/t7VISp/1).

**Details**

- `(?m)` - multiline option making `^`  and `$` match start and end of lines
- `^` - start of a line
- `\h*` - 0+ horizontal whitespaces
- `\K` - match reset operator that omits the text match so far from the memory buffer
- `"` - a double quote
- `|` - or
- `"` - a double quote that...
- `(?=\h*$)` - (a positive lookahead, a non-consuming pattern) is followed with 0+ horizontal whitespaces and the end of line position.

Comment: Ooh, I just knew about `\K`. That is a helpful shortcut for a lookbehind. Does that work in Python?

Comment: @justhalf `\K` is not supported in Python `re`, but it works in Python PyPi `regex` module. See [demo](https://rextester.com/SJKQX93361). However, to remove those quotes in Python 3.5+, I'd use `re.sub(r'(?m)^([^\S\r\n]*)"|"(?=[^\S\r\n]*$)', r'\1', text, flags=re.M)` ([demo](https://rextester.com/RYKIT5127))